# xCode 4 hangs... what to do?

Tags: svn, xcode4

xCode 4 started to hang on any project under svn control. I use a remote repository which is  accessible and works just fine from a command line. The only work around I was able to find is to kill local svn and checkout the whole project again. That seems to work for a bit but then the same problem shows up: xCode just hangs solid a few seconds after I start it.
I would really appreciate any help to resolve this... Can't do anything :(

Please and thanks.

Log shows the following:

```
3/22/11 9:53:22 AM  Xcode[3295] [?T] ASSERTION FAILURE in /SourceCache/IDEFoundation/IDEFoundation-284/Framework/Classes/Model/SourceControl/IDESourceControlTree.m:2548
Details:  (addedItem) should not be nil.
Object:   <IDESourceControlWorkingTree: 0x201bf59a0>
Method:   -mergeStatusOperationResults:forLocalStatusOnly:
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x201bbb320>{name = (null), num = 13}
Hints:   None

3/22/11 9:53:22 AM  Xcode[3295] [?T] 
Backtrace:
  0  0x0000000100949843 -[IDEAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:fileName:lineNumber:messageFormat:arguments:] (in IDEKit)
  1  0x000000010006d484 _DVTAssertionFailureHandler (in DVTFoundation)
  2  0x000000010055f071 __78-[IDESourceControlWorkingTree mergeStatusOperationResults:forLocalStatusOnly:]_block_invoke_0 (in IDEFoundation)
  3  0x00000001000060cc __38-[DVTDispatchLock performLockedBlock:]_block_invoke_0 (in DVTFoundation)
  4  0x00007fff87da14db dispatch_barrier_sync_f (in libSystem.B.dylib)
  5  0x0000000100006073 -[DVTDispatchLock performLockedBlock:] (in DVTFoundation)
  6  0x000000010055db83 -[IDESourceControlWorkingTree mergeStatusOperationResults:forLocalStatusOnly:] (in IDEFoundation)
  7  0x00000001005dcd0c __77-[IDESourceControlWorkingTree updateLocalStatusForDirectory:completionBlock:]_block_invoke_01137 (in IDEFoundation)
  8  0x00007fff87da8284 _dispatch_call_block_and_release (in libSystem.B.dylib)
  9  0x00007fff87d86df2 _dispatch_queue_drain (in libSystem.B.dylib)
 10  0x00007fff87d86c54 _dispatch_queue_invoke (in libSystem.B.dylib)
 11  0x00007fff87d867fe _dispatch_worker_thread2 (in libSystem.B.dylib)
 12  0x00007fff87d86128 _pthread_wqthread (in libSystem.B.dylib)
 13  0x00007fff87d85fc5 start_wqthread (in libSystem.B.dylib)
```

Comment: I have the exact same problem. Have you found any solutions yet? I didn't have this problem with the GM seed of XCode 4.

Comment: @GrAnD, I'm just wondering if you had any files in your working copy that were added, but not yet committed to your repository. The issue seems to point to Xcode's interaction with SVN with the second line there. "Details:  (addedItem) should not be nil."

Comment: I've found a workaround that seems to work 100% of the time. If your xcode hangs on SVN access on one of your projects simple kill it, open again and without opening the project in question goto organizer and under repositories remove a reference to that projects' repository (a blue folder icon). then open your project and all would be back to normal. xcode will recreate the reference automatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Renaming my working directory also worked for me. It is a pain but i just rename it back when I need to do a check-in.  Also note, that I updated to xcode 4.0.2 this morning and it has the same problem.

Answer (score 8):

Deleting if from "Organizer -> Repositories" does help.

Comment: Worked for me when I had the same problem!

Answer (score 1):

I do have the same problem and can workaround temporarily by renaming the local working directory on my MAC.

Answer (score 1):

I had multiple checkouts from same repo, deleting duplicates solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Every time I tried to open a project in XCode 4.0.2 GA, I'd get the beach ball and eventually the stack trace above. My subversion repository is on a remote host that I am connecting to over ssh. When I looked at the repositories under Window > Organizer the repository in question was in 'yellow' status. XCode seemed to be stuck trying to check out the code.

I did two things

1) Set up key authorization instead of password. This didn't do much.

2) I removed the svn repository on the remote host. On my local host I found all of the the .svn directories

find . -name '.svn' -print

and deleted them. Then I updated the global ignore list in the ~./subversion/config directory to look like

global-ignores = *.o *.lo *.la #*# .*.rej *.rej .*~ *~ .#* .DS_Store *.mode1v3 *.pbxuser build xcuserdata

It was freezing on the xcuserdata directory.

Then I recreated the subversion repository on the remote host and reimported the project from my local host.

Now it seems to work!

I am not sure the impact this will have on multiple users editing the project. I am using svn to keep the project sync'd among my own machines.

Hope this helps,
rdp